# Ccomponent velocity toward 90 degrees and 180 degrees

Tags: vectors, physics

An airplane flies towards $149^\circ$ at $525km/h$. What is the component of the plane's velocity a) toward $90^\circ$? b) toward $180^\circ$?

I know how to find the horizontal component and vertical component.  Respectively, they are: $525*\cos(149)$ and $525\sin(149)$.  What I don't understand is what does "toward $90^\circ$" and "toward $180^\circ$" mean?  I have never seen a question stated this way before and could not find it anywhere else.

Thanks
Bhaumik Patel

Answer (score 1):

The problem just states the direction of the axes. If you draw these on paper, the 90$^\circ$ axis points up on the page, the 180$^\circ$ points towards left. But this is a pretty simple case. The problem could have asked you to calculate components along any axis, say 45$^\circ$. The way to get the answer is 525*cos(149-45). Just to verify that this is correct, the "horizontal" component is at 0$^\circ$, so 525*cos(149-0)=525*cos(149). The "vertical" component is at 90$^\circ$, so 525*cos(149-90)=525*sin(149)